# Referencing a package. mrt:sax

Tags: meteor

I've installed a package like this:

```
meteor add mrt:sax
```

When I've used sax.js on a MEAN stack I've accessed it like this:

```
var sax = require("sax")
var parser = sax.parser(strict)
```

How do I use it in Meteor?  Or any non-standard package installed from Atmosphere?  I'm using sax.js exclusively on the server to parse xml received from an http call to an external web resource.

I've tried various alternatives:

```
var parser = Meteor.sax.parser(strict)
var parser = Meteor.mrt_sax.parser(strict)
var sax = Npm.require("sax")
var sax = Npm.require("mrt_sax")
```

And a few others besides.
I cannot find a beginners guide to getting access to installed packages ...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the github repository for this package: [github.com/praus/meteor-sax-js](https://github.com/praus/meteor-sax-js)
and it hasn't been updated since May 17, 2013.  I imagine that it won't work with the latest release of Meteor.

You can wrap npm packages as discussed in the [discover meteor blog](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/wrapping-npm-packages/).

Comment: The package I've used is 'unclaimed' and dates from August last year. https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/sax.  But, perhaps, I need to start with the npm module and repackage for meteor, or simply use the npm module.  I will try both and given that I've not done this before I'll learn something too.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got this working like this.

Removed mrt:sax

```
meteor remove mrt:sax
```

Installed meteorhacks:npm and sax

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
npm install sax
```

Edited my packages.json

```
{'sax','1.1.4'}
```

Accessed sax like this:

```
var sax = Meteor.npmRequire('sax'),
strict = true,
parser = sax.parser(strict),
...
```

The parser method is asynchronous, so called it like so:

```
    var xmlParser = Async.wrap(Meteor.myFunctions.parsingXML); 
    var jsonResult = xmlParser(response.content);
```

Where response.content is the xml returned from the http GET request.